# Is the Linux kernel a single program?

Tags: linux

I understand that there are many programs loaded on bootup, but I was wondering about the thing referred to as "the" Linux kernel. Is it a single program that loads others? Is it multiple programs?

Comment: That depends both on how you define "program" and also how you define "single" (in particular, whether you consider modules to be separate or not). What is your definition of "program", and your criteria for when something is a "single" program vs. multiple programs?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Good points.  My definition would be "a single executable file"

Comment: Great question @Michael Stachowsky (I was just wondering the same thing myself). I'm trying to learn the fundamental knowledge of Linux and Linux-derived machines. This vote status is not right IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a single program that does a lot of things (often known as [a *monolithic* kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolithic_kernel)). Usually it's loaded from the `vmlinuz` file in your /boot partition. (See also "initramfs".)

Many parts of the Linux kernel can be compiled as modules and loaded from .ko files on demand, but once loaded they still behave as if they're an integral part of the kernel "process".